# Can't download file from Raspberry Pi Pico to MacBook Pro

Tags: pi-pico

I'm using a Raspberry Pi Pico to control a coffee machine. As part of tuning the PID controller, I'm writing to a `data.csv` file on the pico, then downloading that to my MacBook Pro Silicon running Ventura for analysis.

On my old MacBook (Intel) I could right-click on the file (in Thonny) and download it to my MacBook, but now I'm getting an error message

```
/data.csv (135 bytes)

Error: Could not copy /data.csv to /data.csv: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/data.csv'
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: You appear to be attempting to save files in the root directory. This is owned by root and even on Linux you need root privileges to write there. It is unclear what you are actually trying but you should be able to save to a user directory.

Comment: There is no option to choose the destination of the file as far as I can see.  When I right click on the file the only download option is "download to /"

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a question regarding Macbook - it's only periherally concerned with the Raspberry Pico.